# Fixing error 408 on first POST request when scraping data

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape website with BS4. This is the website that I have:

https://www.wsl.ch/de/ueber-die-wsl/news/alle-news.html

I want to scrape all urls of the news articles that are on this page. If I just put url in request lib, I will not get URLs of the website. But If i go to inspect page -> network, there is one post request that returns HTML that has all urls ( href-s ).
I have to use post request In order to get all URLs on the website, but the problem is that Im always getting error 408.

```
url = 'https://www.wsl.ch/de/ueber-die-wsl/news/alle-news.filter.html?tx_wslfilter_filter%5Baction%5D=ajax&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcontroller%5D=Filter&cHash=88a50dfb12c7c7e03ce68f244dbfda20'

headers = {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': '757',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Host': 'www.wsl.ch',
            'Origin': 'https://www.wsl.ch',
            'Referer': 'https://www.wsl.ch/de/ueber-die-wsl/news/alle-news.html',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'Server-Timing': 'miss, db;dur=63, app;dur=55.2'}


response = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I have tried with and without headers but its the same.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are not sending body in your post request.
- I have corrected your code, now you will not get 408 (timeout)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.wsl.ch/de/ueber-die-wsl/news/alle-news.filter.html?tx_wslfilter_filter%5Baction%5D=ajax&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcontroller%5D=Filter&cHash=88a50dfb12c7c7e03ce68f244dbfda20'

headers = {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': '757',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Host': 'www.wsl.ch',
            'Origin': 'https://www.wsl.ch',
            'Referer': 'https://www.wsl.ch/de/ueber-die-wsl/news/alle-news.html',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'Server-Timing': 'miss, db;dur=63, app;dur=55.2'}

data='tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btype%5D=news&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bslf%5D=0&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Blang%5D=0&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bpage%5D=1&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bperpage%5D=10&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bkeyword%5D=&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Ball%5D=1&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcategory%5D%5B10%5D=10&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcategory%5D%5B11%5D=11&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcategory%5D%5B12%5D=12&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcategory%5D%5B13%5D=13&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Bcategory%5D%5B1%5D=1&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B76%5D=76&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B1%5D=1&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B11%5D=11&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B7%5D=7&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B9%5D=9&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B8%5D=8&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Btag%5D%5B52%5D=52&tx_wslfilter_filter%5Byear%5D=0'
response = requests.post(url,data=data, headers = headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```